# Установить высоту через jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Помогите, пожалуйста, поправить скрипт.

На [страничке](http://prozaik.16mb.com/js2/tabs_handmade/) не получается установить высоту для `.labelContainerText` такую же, как у `#labelContainer`. Устанавливаю при помощи jquery в функции `init()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.labelContainerText').height = $('#labelContainer').height;
$('#labelContainer').resize(function() {
    $('.labelContainerText').height = $('#labelContainer').height;
});
```

Примерно так, в первой строчке изменяем размер, во второй ставим обработчик на изменение размера **#labelContainer**.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#labelContainer').height(например500);
```

Так?

Comment: нет. установить высоту нужно для .labelContainerText, а вы установили для #labelContainer. да ещё при том фиксированную. в моём случае количество контента динамическое. затем и использую js

Answer (score 0):

```
function doResize(){
    $('.labelContainerText').height($('#labelContainer').height());
}
doResize();
$('#labelContainer').resize(function() {
    doResize();
});
```